# jqGrid Grouping Without Subgrids?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grouping

Is it possible to group in jqgrid without using subgrids ? I just want a heading that spans all columns with the group title, not a subgrid with different headings. The only examples of grouping I can find seem to use a full subgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid 3.8 now supports grouping without subgrids.

See: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=690

Answer (score 1):

As Sonny noted, grouping is now part of jqGrid - you can see the demos on [this page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under Grouping.

Originally I thought you meant grouping of column headers, which is still not supported by jqGrid: [jqGrid Forum - about-grouping-column-header](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/about-grouping-column-header/&value=header&type=1&include=1&search=1). It would be a nice feature, though.

Comment: Can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939096/hide-grouping-heading-in-jqgrid-if-every-row-inside-it-is-hidden) please