# How to catch keyboard keys if jqueryUI datepicker is active

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid

jqgrid column contains jqueryUI DataPicker used in inline edit mode.
If DataPicker input element has focus and Ctrl+S or some other key is is pressed, body_onkeydown is not executed:  IE9 invokes ctrl+s default behaviour (save dialog). In FireFox body_onkeydown is also not executed.

How to fix this code so keys can catched if DatePicker has focus ?

DatePicker is defined as:

```
    $(elem).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        autoSize: true,
        showOn: 'button', 
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showWeek: true
    });
```

Code used to catch ctrl+s keypress is:

```
$(function () {
    $("html").keydown(body_onkeydown);
});


function body_onkeydown(evt) {
    // Why this function is not executed if datepicker has focus?
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 83: $("#grid_savebutton").click(); break;         
              }
        cancel(evt);
        return false;
    }

function cancel(evt) {
    evt.returnValue = false;
    evt.keyCode = 0;
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question! In the code of jqGrid you can fine sometime `return false` or [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) inside of event handles which I personally find unneeded. In your case the problem make the line 8237 of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` (in version 4.1.2) or the line 87 of the grid.inlinedit.js (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L87)):

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

If you comment the like the inline editing will not more stop propagation of the `keydown` event and how you could see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingDatepicker.htm) you will be able to catch <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> during inline editing.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent. I added this patch. Maybe it is better to move this line inside if in `if (e.keyCode === 27) { $($t).jqGrid("restoreRow", rowid, afterrestorefunc); e.stopPropagation(); }` to block esc key propagation. Btw. have you looked to the issue described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558869/how-to-show-autocomplete-field-value-in-form-editing

Comment: @Andrus: Yes! It sounds good. Just try this, but I think you are right. Last time I had less free time, so I posted less answers as before on the stackoverflow. I hope at the end of the week I will have more time.

Comment: @Andrus: By the way, I spend many time in working on the new jqGrid feature: multi-rows column header (groups of column headers) see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeadersWithFirstRow4.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341339/jqgrid-column-group/7351638#7351638). The work is still not finished, but I am sure that in the next version of jqGrid, which will be published in about 10 days, will be the multi-header feature (groups of column headers) in some form.

Comment: thank you. Will patch from this answer also included in next release of jqGrid? I havent seen any information about next release date. It is interesting that e.stopPropagation() enables IE9 default Ctrl+S behaviour (save dialog). It should disable Ctrl+S completely.

Comment: @Andrus: You can read about the new release [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/d2648c048a04571677eb86132ea3ddd0899afb15#commitcomment-613764). To have patches like with `stopPropagation` you should post bug report in the trirand forum.

Comment: Thank you. I posted it in http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/keyboard-shortcuts-are-not-working-in-inline-edit-can-oleg-patch-applied/ . Thank for the git link. I found from this code which allows to add and edit file data in jqgrid with other row data. Is it reasonable to use this or is http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2011/03/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-form-editing-with.html upload method better?