# Is there anyway to get jqgrid with group column headers and still support sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid, header

i see there [is a new version of jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and it [now supports having grouped column headers](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar)

I do see that if you use it, sorting them becomes disabled for any column that is in a group.  Does anyone know if there is any work around to this as I can't turn off sorting (as its being used today) but i would like to be able to leverage this new feature to group sets of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it's misunderstanding. One can **sort any column** if one uses grouped column headers. What is **not supported is the usage of `sortable:true` jqGrid option**. The option allows you to change the order of columns per drag & drop of column headers.

If you look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeadersNew2.htm) or another more generic [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeadersNew4.htm), which was the origin for the code currently used in jqGrid (see [the comments](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ade910682a03d633737ef1499f46675122d1b86e#comments) and [the previous one](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/f2dbfad6722f531cc21c136772f4b8ca9c0f8c3d#comments)), you will see that you do can sort any column. More early I prepared some demos in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341339/jqgrid-column-group/7351638#7351638).

Current [limitation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:groupingheadar#limitations) can be eliminated, but one need just place a little more code in jqGrid. Tony (the developer of jqGrid) wanted not make too many changes at once and to publish the version 4.2.0. The version has very important fixes for jQuery 1.6.3 and 1.6.4, so if one would publish new version later many people could receive compatibility problems and spend there time.

Comment: `The option allows you to change the order of rows per drag & drop.` I think you mean Columns.