# How can I center align text in jqgrid header group

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, header

I am using [the new header grouping feature of jqgrid 4.2](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=857) which works great except that it left aligns all of the text in the header groups.

How can align the header group text to be center in the cell?

Here is a screenshot to show you how it seems to be working by default:  (I want "Books" to be center aligned")

NOTE: the regular column headers ARE center aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeadersNew5.htm) produce the following grid with the center alignment column headers:

[image]

If you would post your demo one can examine where is the problem's origin. I suppose that some other CSS which you make the problem.

Comment: can you think of what css id would drive the formatting of the group header as i must have some conflicting css?

Comment: @leora: It's difficult to say. It's the same question as you asked me "How many money I have in my purse?". I can nothing say about the CSS which you use without have seen it. Could you post URL to the demo which reproduce the problem? If I would examine the real CSS which applied to the column header group I could answer on the question.

Comment: fair enough . . i will try to reproduce an isolated example online.

Comment: @leora: I would help you if I could, but I can't now. In my environment I don't have the problem. So if you would have an example, just post the URL to me and I will look inside.

Answer (score 8):

The header group cell is given special class .ui-th-column-header. However this class has no special styling, if anywere in your project you have set text-align to left for th elements (for example in ASP.NET MVC the site.css is doing this) the text will not be center aligned. In most situations adding this to your CSS should do the trick:

```
.ui-th-column-header
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but i found the solution. you give **titleText** within the html center tag

titleText: ' open center tag Books close center tag'

Answer (score 1):

I had to center align text in table head columns in jqgrid, after element inspection, the following worked in my case:

```
.ui-jqgrid-sortable {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`$('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-th-div').css('text-align', 'center');`

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element then , get the id of the element

```
    $('#jqgh_grid-table_CountryName').css('text-align', 'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

this work

```
  jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
                useColSpanStyle: false,//or true
                groupHeaders: [
                    { startColumnName: 'colName', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<center>your text</center>' }
                ]
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).